# Enable download in background with phonegap ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, background-process

I am using phonegap 2.2.0 to develop an ios app. The app requires to download some videos which i'm doing with the FileTransfer. The problem is if the app goes background i.e if the screen is locked or if the home key is pressed, download gets cancelled. I need to continue downloading the videos even when the app is in background. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your app gets suspended after a short period of being in background mode, so it is no longer executing code. You need to either declare and implement your app as a service (UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist), or delay the suspension (in applicationDidEnterBackground handler). Both cases are tricky if you are a pure PhoneGap developer.

I wrote a small PhoneGap [plugin](https://github.com/hermankan/BackgroundMode) for iOS that checks whether the app has called for background mode, and if so prevents it from getting suspended (normally up to 10 minutes) until the mode is revoked.

See [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for more detail.